# Influential case - to remove or not to remove?

Tags: regression, mediation, cooks-distance

I'm doing a multiple regression analysis with 3 predictor variables (RELAT, SSS and FAITH), and the criterion variable is SSE. I have found that SSS is a mediator between RELAT and SSE, and FAITH is a separate predictor which adds to the model:

[image: model]

However, I have identified that there is one influential case. The Cook's distance is .35, and the covariance ratio is just under 1 - [3(k + 1)/n],
which, as I understand it, means the case should be removed. After removing it, I ran correlations again, and RELAT no longer correlates with SSE. So I've run the regression without RELAT.

In the original model, R square = .43, RMSE = 9.63. After removing the influential case and excluding RELAT from the regression, R square = .37, RMSE = 8.96. So the original model explains more variance, but the model without the influential case and without RELAT in the regression has lower RMSE, meaning its predictions are more accurate. Is that correct? Which model should I go with here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 1):

The danger wrt to an influential observation is that the outcome is totally unrelated to the observed variables. For example, if you had done a survey of Jamaican high school track athletes in 2002 relating their training methods to their track times, and happened to include Usain Bolt as a subject, it is likely that whatever methods he used would have appeared unduly effective due to Bolt's degree of natural aptitude. In short, where removing one influential case changes the outcome, you need to be very careful, and it is very unlikely if your goal is prediction, that results depending on the influential case will generalise well. For example, adopting Bolt's choice of shoe or breakfast as a schoolboy is unlikely to assist any other athlete significantly. If it is possible, though, it may be instructive to attempt to find out more about the influential case, and how it differs from the other cases (this obviously presumes you were involved in collecting the data or can communicate with the people how were).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's for an assignment, so I wasn't involved in collecting the data. The variable RELAT is relationship status, the criterion SSE is sexual self efficacy. Looking at the data, the influential case is a person not in a relationship, and her sexual self efficacy is lower than anyone else. So she's like the Usain Bolt of poor sexual self efficacy...

Comment: Fair enough - I'm not sure how SSE is measured or formally defined, but it seems intuitive that it is an area where differences between individuals could be extremely difficult to model using observable variables. For example, in the present case it might be reasonable to wonder about a medical or family history reason for the especially low SSE. Identifying variables for future research can be a useful outcome.

Comment: I think I should conclude that she's influencing the model too much on her own. Her SSE score is 3.40 SD below the mean, and if she met someone and got into a relationship next week, her data would make the variable of relationship status non-significantly related to SSE. It's like her version of Usain Bolt's breakfast cereal, maybe. The better model is the one with the lower RMSE anyway, right? Not the model with the higher R square?